# Autostart workflow in sp2013 gets suspended with "There has been an error authenticating the request.", however

Tags: c#, sharepoint, workflow

Let me try to describe the situation..

**Site A:**
Is meant is an catch all site, with only 1 library. This is used by an third party software, that send all the items to 1 location with specified information. Behind this is an timerjob, that sends all the items to their respective sites/libraries.  (so doesn't stay on Site A)

**Site X:**
When an new item is added through the timerjob on Site A. An workflow is started, however the workflow is randomly sunspended with a the same error. A manual start on the same item will allways succeed. Thus only the autostart that gets suspended.

Workflow is made in visual studio and is widely used in the application without problems.

---

The **error** message:

> Details: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the
>   workflow instance. Exception details: System.ApplicationException:
>   HTTP 401 {"error_description":"The server was unable to process the
>   request due to an internal error. For more information about the
>   error, either turn on IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults (either from
>   ServiceBehaviorAttribute or from the  configuration
>   behavior) on the server in order to send the exception information
>   back to the client, or turn on tracing as per the Microsoft .NET
>   Framework SDK documentation and inspect the server trace logs."}
>   {"x-ms-diagnostics":["3001000;reason=\"There has been an error
>   authenticating the
>   request.\";category=\"invalid_client\""],"SPRequestGuid":["c0fb74e8-6b48-0deb-85c4-7fdab324d2f7"],"request-id":["c0fb74e8-6b48-0deb-85c4-7fdab324d2f7"],"X-FRAME-OPTIONS":["SAMEORIGIN"],"SPRequestDuration":["17"],"SPIisLatency":["0"],"Server":["Microsoft-IIS/8.5"],"WWW-Authenticate":["Bearer
>   realm=\"97b27fa4-494a-4bff-a6a0-00b798335a86\",client_id=\"00000003-0000-0ff1-ce00-000000000000\",trusted_issuers=\"00000005-0000-0000-c000-000000000000@*,00000003-0000-0ff1-ce00-000000000000@97b27fa4-494a-4bff-a6a0-00b798335a86\"","Negotiate","NTLM"],"X-Powered-By":["ASP.NET"],"MicrosoftSharePointTeamServices":["15.0.0.4687"],"X-Content-Type-Options":["nosniff"],"X-MS-InvokeApp":["1;
>   RequireReadOnly"],"Date":["Mon, 14 Jan 2019 13:47:12 GMT"]} at
>   Microsoft.Activities.Hosting.Runtime.Subroutine.SubroutineChild.Execute(CodeActivityContext
>   context) at
>   System.Activities.CodeActivity.InternalExecute(ActivityInstance
>   instance, ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager)
>   at
>   System.Activities.Runtime.ActivityExecutor.ExecuteActivityWorkItem.ExecuteBody(ActivityExecutor
>   executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager, Location resultLocation)

Tried many given solutions (User Sync (however manual start with the same user is not a problem)), Workflow App Permissions feature ..

Comment: How about you do the step "For more information about the error, either turn on IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults (either from ServiceBehaviorAttribute or from the configuration behavior) on the server in order to send the exception information back to the client, or turn on tracing as per the Microsoft .NET Framework SDK documentation and inspect the server trace logs." so you actually have the Debug information you are looking for?